# I'm getting empty array what is wrong?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want the universities  that have the string "Uni" included in their name. then, Create a new array called uni that contains them all. I've use the HOF method still didn't work.

```js
var graduates = [{ id: 4, first_name: "Modestine", university: "International Medical & Technological University", email: "mdolder3@symantec.com" },
  { id: 5, first_name: "Chick", university: "Sultan Salahuddin Abdul Aziz Shah Polytechnic", email: "camorts4@google.com.au" },
  { id: 6, first_name: "Jakob", university: "Fachhochschule Rosenheim, Hochschule für Technik und Wirtschaft", email: "jharken5@spiegel.de" },
  { id: 7, first_name: "Robbi", university: "Salem University", email: "rbrister6@redcross.org" },
  { id: 8, first_name: "Colline", university: "Coastal Carolina University", email: "cbrosh7@alibaba.com" },
  { id: 9, first_name: "Michail", university: "Universidad Católica de Ávila", email: "mrome8@shinystat.com" },
  { id: 10, first_name: "Hube", university: "Universitat Rovira I Virgili Tarragona", email: "hlethbrig9@foxnews.com" }]

const unisWithUni = [];
console.log(unisWithUni);
for (let i = 0; i < graduates.length; i++) {
  if (graduates[i].university === "Uni") {
    unisWithUni.push(graduates[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: you seem to be missing some of the code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `graduates[i].university === "Uni"` to `graduates[i].university.includes("Uni")` this way any string that contains 'Uni' will be found, otherwise it will only match exactly "Uni".

Also, put your `console.log(unisWithUni);` after the for loop.

```js
var graduates = [{ id: 4, first_name: "Modestine", university: "International Medical & Technological University", email: "mdolder3@symantec.com" },
  { id: 5, first_name: "Chick", university: "Sultan Salahuddin Abdul Aziz Shah Polytechnic", email: "camorts4@google.com.au" },
  { id: 6, first_name: "Jakob", university: "Fachhochschule Rosenheim, Hochschule für Technik und Wirtschaft", email: "jharken5@spiegel.de" },
  { id: 7, first_name: "Robbi", university: "Salem University", email: "rbrister6@redcross.org" },
  { id: 8, first_name: "Colline", university: "Coastal Carolina University", email: "cbrosh7@alibaba.com" },
  { id: 9, first_name: "Michail", university: "Universidad Católica de Ávila", email: "mrome8@shinystat.com" },
  { id: 10, first_name: "Hube", university: "Universitat Rovira I Virgili Tarragona", email: "hlethbrig9@foxnews.com" }]

const unisWithUni = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < graduates.length; i++) {
    if (graduates[i].university.includes("Uni")) {
      unisWithUni.push(graduates[i]);
    }

}

console.log(unisWithUni);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a complete string. In javascript (or almost any language) "equal" don't means "contains". So `"hi" === "hi what's up"` is not the same, they are not equal.

In JavasSript you want to look for `indexOf()` (old&new browsers) or `includes()` (new browsers), so:

```js
 var graduates = [
     { id: 4, first_name: "Modestine", university: "International Medical & Technological University", email: "mdolder3@symantec.com" },
    { id: 5, first_name: "Chick", university: "Sultan Salahuddin Abdul Aziz Shah Polytechnic", email: "camorts4@google.com.au" },
    { id: 6, first_name: "Jakob", university: "Fachhochschule Rosenheim, Hochschule für Technik und Wirtschaft", email: "jharken5@spiegel.de" },
    { id: 7, first_name: "Robbi", university: "Salem University", email: "rbrister6@redcross.org" },
    { id: 8, first_name: "Colline", university: "Coastal Carolina University", email: "cbrosh7@alibaba.com" },
    { id: 9, first_name: "Michail", university: "Universidad Católica de Ávila", email: "mrome8@shinystat.com" },
    { id: 10, first_name: "Hube", university: "Universitat Rovira I Virgili Tarragona", email: "hlethbrig9@foxnews.com"}
];

const unisWithUni = [];
for (let i = 0; i < graduates.length; i++) {
  if (graduates[i].university.indexOf("Uni") > -1) {
    unisWithUni.push(graduates[i]);
  }
}
console.log(unisWithUni);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example that uses jQuery's `map()`.  Why, just because.

**Note** that I convert the university to lowercase before searching for the string `uni` making the search case insensitive.

```js
var graduates = [{
    id: 4,
    first_name: "Modestine",
    university: "International Medical & Technological University",
    email: "mdolder3@symantec.com"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    first_name: "Chick",
    university: "Sultan Salahuddin Abdul Aziz Shah Polytechnic",
    email: "camorts4@google.com.au"
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    first_name: "Jakob",
    university: "Fachhochschule Rosenheim, Hochschule für Technik und Wirtschaft",
    email: "jharken5@spiegel.de"
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    first_name: "Robbi",
    university: "Salem University",
    email: "rbrister6@redcross.org"
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    first_name: "Colline",
    university: "Coastal Carolina University",
    email: "cbrosh7@alibaba.com"
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    first_name: "Michail",
    university: "Universidad Católica de Ávila",
    email: "mrome8@shinystat.com"
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    first_name: "Hube",
    university: "Universitat Rovira I Virgili Tarragona",
    email: "hlethbrig9@foxnews.com"
  }
];

var unisWithUni = $.map(graduates, grad => {
  return grad.university.toLowerCase().includes("uni") ? grad : null;
});

console.log(unisWithUni);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: But but but... If you use ES6 arrow functions, at least use ES6 map. If there are arrow functions, there's map. No reason to use jQuery. Is like moving a Ferrari by pulling with horses xD. Also, with this you get an array full of `null`s. Better use `filter()` instead. With `filter` is a way more elegant solution, actually.